# Unable to get ModelAttribute member variable in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, modelattribute

I have the following class.

```
class Bar {

   public Bar(String fooVal) {
      this.foo = fooVal;
   }

   private String foo; 

   public String getFoo() {
       return this.foo;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return this.foo;
   }
```

}

The following controller

```
class Controller {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView() {
        return new ModelAndView("barJSP", "barModel", new Bar("testFooVal"));
    }
}
```

And now I am trying to access in jsp the value of foo.

I have the following two variants of JSP in the barJSP trying to print the foo Vals.

```
<% System.out.println(pageContext.findAttribute("barModel.foo")); %>
```

This prints null. However

```
<% System.out.println(pageContext.findAttribute("barModel")); %>
```

This prints testFooVal as expected (it actually prints the thing that toString() returns).

My understanding of jsp syntax is that . is used to access members and should work as long as getters are defined for it. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JSP EL` for easily accessing objects:

```
 ${barModel.foo}
```

Otherwise, you have to import model class and cast for converting:

```
<%@ page import="com.example.model.Bar"%>
<% Bar b = (Bar)(pageContext.findAttribute("barModel"));
   out.println(b.getFoo());
%>
```

Comment: @ArunavSanyal ${barModel.foo} invoke getFoo() method implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

The method `findAttribute()` searches for the specified attribute in all four levels in the following order – Page, Request, Session and Application. 
It returns `NULL` when no attribute found at any of the level.

In the following case

```
<% System.out.println(pageContext.findAttribute("barModel.foo")); %>
```

the attribute `barModel.foo` is not accessible because it is a `private` variable in the class and the method will not find it. So it returns `NULL`.

But in the case of

`<% System.out.println(pageContext.findAttribute("barModel")); %>`

the attribute `barModel` is available in the context and when you print it will automatically call the `toString()` method.

Comment: My understanding of spring mvc was the model attribute private members are accessible provided there exists a gettter for it. I dont want to break encapsulation.